# From javascript to php with curl

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I create this javascript with json. It is for Soft one program (web services).
It is ok but i need this in php and curl. Any suggestion?

```
<script>
    function getLoginJSON()
    {
            var xhr;
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://demo.oncloud.gr/s1services?login";

        xhr.open("POST", url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origins", "application/json");
        var data = JSON.stringify({"service":"login", "username":"demo", "password":"demo", "appId":"156"}); // appId: Μια παράμετρος του softOne
        xhr.send(data);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () 
        {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) 
                document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        };
    }
</script>
```

Wait Server response .....

Comment: I am not sure what suggestions you are looking for. My suggestion would be to try to do this in PHP using cURL.

Comment: Yes i know this any examples? thanks

Comment: Yes here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
$data = [
'service' => 'login',
'username' => 'demo',
'password' => 'demo',
'appId' => '156'
];

$postData = json_encode($data); //create json

$ch = curl_init('http://demo.oncloud.gr/s1services?login'); //initialize curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); //attach json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch); //send and fetch result
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //get http code
curl_close($ch);

if($httpcode === 200) {
    echo '<p>' . $result . '</p>'; //print the result
}
```